# How to separate Quadratic formula between delta and x' and x''?

Tags: equations

New on Tex, LaTex. Hoping this is not a difficult question:

This is the LaTex for the quadratic equation formula:

```
$$\begin{array}{*{20}c} {x = \frac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac} }}{{2a}}} & {{\rm{when}}} & {ax^2 + bx + c = 0} \\ \end{array}$$
```

How to I separate this between Delta and X in a way I have also x', x''?

Edit:
This a visual approach of what I am looking for:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the TEX.SE community. I have deleted my answer: `\rm` it is a old command. After I suggest you to this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854

Comment: There are many ways to create your image but the user @oliversm has been great. You not choose my answer...I write truly .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that this is ok:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
  
\begin{document}
\[\begin{matrix}
\Delta =b^2-4ac\\
     x = \dfrac{- b\pm\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{2a}\\[.5em]
     x' = \dfrac{- b+\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{2a}\\[.5em]
     x'' = \dfrac{- b-\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{2a}
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

Using the `\cdot`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
  
\begin{document}
\[\begin{matrix}
\Delta =b^2-4\cdot a\cdot c\\
     x = \dfrac{- b\pm\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{2\cdot a}\\[.5em]
     x' = \dfrac{- b+\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{2\cdot a}\\[.5em]
     x'' = \dfrac{- b-\sqrt{b^2- 4ac}}{2\cdot a}
\end{matrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason to use `matrix` instead of `gather*`?

Comment: @Teepeemm Very kind Teepeemm I have seen only the original code that there is an `array` and I have thinked to use a `matrix` considering that the user was a newbie with LaTeX(TeX). Just it only this the reason. If you see my 2nd comment I have written "there are many ways to create your image" and I have written that the user @oliversm has been great...and I not want that the user check my answer.

Answer (score 6):

For the Delta and X there is no need for any particular alignment, so I think `gather` is what you want here. Whereas for `x'` and `x''` you want `align`. Also, for big fractions you want to display, use `dfrac` (from `amsmath`), and for some short bits of text between equations, use `shortintertext` from `mathtools`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
For a quadratic with determinant $ \Delta $ where
\begin{gather}
\Delta = b^2 - 4ac, \\
\shortintertext{we have the general solution}
x = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}.
\end{gather}
This has the two roots $ x' $ and $ x'' $ given by
\begin{align}
x'  & = \dfrac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} \\
\shortintertext{and}
x'' & = \dfrac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}. 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As an aside, consider using `x^+` and `x^-` instead of the prime notation, as it makes things clearer, as people will think you're talking about derivatives.